# Find Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $$f(z):=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z^2+1}$$ and let $$\sum_{k}a_kz^k$$ with k in Z the Laurent series of $f(z)$ for $0<|z|<1$. I have to find a formula for $a_k$. I've tried a lot, but I'm stuck. Can somebody help me? I want to do it with ordening of absolute series.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$e^\frac{1}{z}=1+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2!} \frac{1}{z^2}+ \dots$$ as well as the geometric expansion$$\frac{1}{z^2+1}=1-z^2+z^4 -+ \dots $$
valid in the annulus $0<|z|<1$. Multiply the two and collect coefficients from terms of the same degree.

Comment: Can you explain the multiplying?

Comment: @RoosJansen For example, the constant term is made of $1 \cdot 1-1 \cdot \frac{1}{2!}+1 \cdot \frac{1}{4!} -+ \dots=\cos(1)$. In order to do this I've paired the coefficient of $z^{-2n}$ of the geometric series with the coefficient of $z^{+2n}$ in the exponential and summed over all $n$. This should be done for all powers, but don't expect a closed form for the resulting sums.

Comment: Hm, I was looking for the method of rearraging the terms if the summation converges absolutely..

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{e^{1/z}}{1+z^2}=\left(1+\frac1z+\frac1{2z^2}+\ldots\right)\left(1-z^2+z^4-z^6+\ldots\right)=$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^{-k}}{k!}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^kz^{2k}$$

Now multiply within the *common* convergence radius...

Comment: I think that the indices in the sums must be different? So in the first sum for example k and in the second n?

Comment: It really doesn't mind how you denote the indices. If it helps clearity one of them can be changed...

Comment: Ok. But I don't understand the multiplying.